# get weekday intervals by year and week number in R

Tags: r, date, sas, lubridate, week-number

I am looking to create a dataframe (or tibble) that can provide weekly intervals by year and I can't quite figure out how to do that.  What I would like is a tibble or data set that looks like this:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- tibble(
  year = rep(2020, 3),
  week_no = 1:3, 
  sas_wk_start = mdy(c(01012020, 01052020, 011202020)),
  sas_wk_end = mdy(c(01042020, 01112020, 01182020)),
  wk_start = mdy(c(01012020, 01082020, 01152020)),
  wk_end = mdy(c(01072020, 01142020, 01212020)),
  iso_wk_start = mdy(12302019, 01062020, 01132020),
  iso_wk_end = mdy(c(01052020, 01122020, 01192020))
)
```

I would also like this to populate where all I would have to change is the year.  The reason I chose the interval Sunday - Saturday is because I am translating code from SAS to R and this appears to be the default weekly interval.  If I am interpreting the SAS functions reference correctly, weeks are determined by the number of Sundays that occur in the time interval.  It would be nice to cross-reference this with other week designations like lubridate's default and the isoweek option.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You would be starting with year and week_no, or just year? or would it be a function that had year and number of weeks to generate?

Comment: I would ideally like to just start with year and have weeks and the intervals populated, as some years might have 52 weeks and other years might have 53.  If this is too complicated I could probably work up designations before hand.

Comment: Can you double check your data as posted? I don't think it aligns with SAS dates correctly and there's typos (2929) making it hard to align with what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo.  The code I am translating from SAS uses the 'INTCK' function which, according to the SAS 9.4 function and call routine guide, appears to count the number of Sundays (p. 686) in a default interval not by 7-day periods.  It might be that I'm confused by this and my interpretation of the first week of January is off?  Anyways, thanks for the help.